# Visual Studio 2010 Unit Testing .NET 3.5 Projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have migrated a .NET 3.5 web application from VS 2008 to 2010 successfully, but am having trouble with unit testing.  I created a Unit Test project and targeted it to .NET 3.5 following Microsoft's instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg601487.aspx.  I also looked at the "Possible Additional Steps" listed at the bottom, but all of the XML mentioned already existed on my system.

Whenever I try to run unit tests, I get this error message: "You can only run tests using the default host adapter from a test assembly that targets .NET framework 3.5."

Comment: When you upgraded, did some of the other projects upgrade to .NET 4.0, or are they also pointing to 3.5?

Comment: Searches for this error message bring up problems when using Pex/Moles.  Are you using those libraries?  See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/4002df5e-18ff-4194-ba86-ed8e946e3de9), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492052/can-tests-be-written-in-3-5-mstest-unit-test-assemblies).

Comment: No Pex/Moles and I just triple checked that everything is .NET 3.5

Comment: I've seen similar problems solved by installing VS2010 SP1. It's much more stable. Also, are you running with MSTest? can try to run with Testdriven.net / Resharper and see if its any better?

Comment: Make sure both projects target .NET 3.5.